# Going back from signed hash with RSA SignHash

Tags: c#, rsa

I'm extremely n00b at this. I'm not even sure if what I'm asking is correct.

I've been asked to decrypt some package, but I found that the package is not being encrypted, instead the package (byte []) has a .zip inside protected with a password.

So now I have to retrieve that password. I tracked it in the code and came to this:

```
lSupraHeader = lCryptoTransformRSA.SignHash(lSupraHeader, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"));
```

lSupraHeader is a Byte [] that contains (between other things) the password. If I get the string from lSupraHeader I can read the password, the problem is that after that "SignHash" I can't get it any more, well, I don't know how to do it.

That code was made a while ago, and change it is not an option for me.

Is there a way to retrieve that password from there? Is is correct what I'm asking whit what I provided or do I need something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to retrieve that password from there?

No.  Once data has been hashed, it cannot be unhashed.

SHA is also known as a "one-way hashing algorithm".  It is designed so that any amount of data can be put into it, and a finite amount of data comes out.  Such things are useful to check to see if two pieces of data are equal, although this method also has flaws (for which there are various workarounds).

Encryption, on the other hand, takes in data, uses a key, and spits out a bunch of random data roughly equal in size to the original data.  Using the same key, the random data can then be unencrypted, or decrypted, to yield the original data.

Having said that:

> I tracked it in the code and came to this:

How did you find that out?  It would appear that you have access to source code and a debugger.  If this is true, then see if you can find an "immediate window" in your debugger.  You may be able to set a breakpoint, execute `Console.WriteLine(whatever)`, and manually retrieve the password that way.  Doing this would leave the original code untouched.

Comment: I can, I'm working on this code. I have access to this source code. The thing is that I need to open that .zip file with what the method returns me (that package with the password-protected .zip inside).

I debugged the code to understand the encrypting process, but found that scenario.

Comment: @NickLScott: I'm confused by what you mean by "package".  Are you implying that you have an arbitrary array of bytes representing a folder or something that contains a zip?  Or that the array of bytes IS the zip? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I have an arbitrary array of bytes that represents the .zip file plus some other things as a header and some more data.

I hope this clears it. My apologies for not being clear enough.

Comment: @NickLScott OK that helps a lot.  So assuming that your questions is "how do I unlock this zip file": you'll need to get the plaintext password and feed that (and the byte array) into some api for dealing with zip files.  I don't know of one offhand, but I'm sure C# has such a thing.  I suspect it will hand you back a directory of files, or some such thing.

Comment: Actually the code has a custom class for that work "FastZip". And as you say, I'd need that password as a string to open the .zip file. Getting the .zip file isn't a problem, the problem is getting the password to open the file.

Reading the code I found that the password was stored in lSupraHeader before it was transformed into what SignHash returns. That was why I was asking if I can get that back. Probably the password is stored somewhere else as well.

Comment: @NickLScott ok so then put a breakpoint on the line of code you have above and in the immediate window (or a watch somewhere) check what the value of `lSupraHeader` is before it gets executed.  Programmatically, though, once `SignHash` is executed and assigned back to the original variable, the original data is unrecoverable.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, I did get the password from lSupraHeader, the problem is that I need to do it programmatically because the password is generated randomly.
I'll try to find it somewhere else then. It must be somewhere else because a device (which inside code I do not have) opens that .zip inside the byte[].
Thanks a lot. At least with this I now know that I need to look somewhere else and not here.

Comment: ahhh ok.  I got you.  Well good luck.  absolute worst case scenario, at least you have a manual solution